# Setting language across whole app - SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, localization

I am looking to add multiple languages to my app and so I have created the different String files and have added them to my localisations. I have a settings page in my app where I want them to be able to select the language the app is in, and the whole app is changed.

```
VStack{
    Button("English"){
        //set app to English
    }
    Button("Francais"){
        //set app to French
    }
    Button("Cymru"){
        //set app to Welsh
    }
    .....
}
```

I've found the modifier `.environment(\.locale, init(identifier: "en"))` but I believe this modifier needs to be added to every view and I was wondering if there is an easier way to do this? I want the language to be saved to user defaults too.

Comment: In a way, the user's preferred languages are already set by the user in the system. You can access that list with `String(Locale.preferredLanguages)`, and the first preferred language with `String(Locale.preferredLanguages).first?.prefix(2)`. So why have the user make the decision once again, instead of just adapting to what the user already prefers? Bad UX, IMHO.